# Source controled folders keep popping up

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

I played around with team foundation Server and visual studio 2012 and I now have 2 folders on my desktop that I keep deleting, but upon opening vs 2012 the pop back again.

Where do i delete them forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your workspaces to see if they are mapped folders. If they are, remove those mappings.